# Trouble sorting aggregated dataframe by column (integer)

Tags: r

I aggregated a table of regions, by the highest price per region.  So, region is only listed once, by the highest price achieved per region.

```
MaxPriceByRegion<- data.frame(aggregate(Price ~ Region, data = Region_Price, max))
```

The result is a nice data frame, showing region and price.

```
Region     Price

WI         2000
IL         10000
ND         4000
AK         20000
```

However, when I try and sort this dataframe by the top 3 regions by price, I run into problems.

I use:

```
Top3 <- MaxPriceByRegion(head([sort(Price), decreasing=TRUE)], 3)
```

I get something to the effect of:

```
NA    Region    Price

NA.1  NA        NA
NA.2  NA        NA
NA.3  NA        NA
   1  WI        2000
NA.4  NA        NA
```

It seems like the sort function is re-expanding my data-frame and nullifying the previous aggregate function.  It's also not sorting properly, as I only want top three regions.

Comment: I think you have a couple syntax errors and you want `order` instead of `sort` , try `Top3 <- head(MaxPriceByRegion[order(MaxPricebyRegion$Price, decreasing=TRUE),],3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Top3 <- head(MaxPriceByRegion[order(MaxPriceByRegion$Price, decreasing=TRUE),],3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with the `dplyr` package.

```
head(arrange(MaxPriceByColor, desc(price)), n=3)
```

To make it reproducible, I used the `dimonds` dataset:

```
MaxPriceByColor <- data.frame(aggregate(price ~ color, data = diamonds, max))
```